# Is there way how to shuffle collection in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I need to shuffle text file with 2.2*10^9 lines. Is there way how I can load it in spark, then shuffle each partition in parallel(for me it is enough to shuffle within scope of partition) and then spill it back to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shuffle only within partitions you can do something like this:

```scala
rdd.mapPartitions(new scala.util.Random().shuffle(_))
```

To shuffle a whole RDD:

```scala
rdd.mapPartitions(iter => {
  val rng = new scala.util.Random()
  iter.map((rng.nextInt, _))
}).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(rdd.partitions.size)).values
```

Comment: @UlysseMizrahi Works just fine, but if you feel like it just edit the answer. It is community wiki for a reason.